# Hide Fields in Order Details - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to know if there is a way to hide or disable fields in the Orders > Order details page in WooCommerce, by using some hook or editing the code. I tried to do it with css display:none in the admin.css file, but for some reason, it hides more than 1 field.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You can filter [`woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b1e76fa68ea488506dbf8c9920ebf843cdf968c2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L90) and [`woocommerce_admin_billing_fields`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b1e76fa68ea488506dbf8c9920ebf843cdf968c2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L41).

Comment: Can you post your final code as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Every field has a own css selector.

[image: See here]